# Python CGI with paramiko

Tags: python, cgi, paramiko

I am trying to write a Python CGI script where user can enter Name(hostname) and Choose Memory from form and then via using paramiko module it will execute free -m command to the given node

```
import cgi
import paramiko

 print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
 print '<html>'
 print '<head><title>My First CGI Program</title></head>'
 print '<body>'
 print '<h1>Hello Program!</h1>'
 form = cgi.FieldStorage()
 if form.getvalue("name"):
 name = form.getvalue("name")
 if form.getvalue("memory"):
 ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
 ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
 ssh.connect(name, username='testuser', password='test12')
    stdin, stdout, stderr=ssh.exec_command("free -m")

 for line in stdout.readlines():
        print line.strip()
 ssh.close()

print '<form method="post" action="final.py">'
print '<p>Name: <input type="text" name="name"/></p>'
print '<input type="checkbox" name="memory" /> Memory'
print '<input type="submit" value="Submit" />'
print '</form>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

It's not throwing error but at the same time it's not giving any output, Not sure What I am doing wrong

Comment: I edited your title. GUI != CGI

Comment: Try to print out the``` stderr ``` for debugging similar to what you are doing for stdout. There could be a command execution error.

Answer (score 1):

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
hostname = form.getvalue("name") or None
if hostname and form.getvalue("memory"):
   ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

   #ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
   #This, of course, is not in the interest of the inventor and is infinitely unsafe,
   #so should only be used in tests in secure networks.
   #The correct way is to have Paramiko load the host keys,
   #so that it can check them as intended like:

   client.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/known_hosts'))
   client.connect(hostname, username="testuser")
   stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('free -m')
   #for test print all std's
   for line in stdin, stdout, stderr:
       print line.strip('\n')
   client.close()
```